# How to Remove Explicit Casting

Tags: scala

How do I remove explicit casting **asInstanceOf[XList[B]]** in `Cons(f(a), b).asInstanceOf[XList[B]]` inside `map` function? Or perhaps redesign `reduce` and `map` functions altogether? Thanks

```
trait XList[+A]
case object Empty extends XList[Nothing]
case class Cons[A](x: A, xs: XList[A]) extends XList[A]

object XList {
  def apply[A](as: A*):XList[A] = if (as.isEmpty) Empty else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  def empty[A]: XList[A] = Empty
}

def reduce[A, B](f: B => A => B)(b: B)(xs: XList[A]): B = xs match {
  case Empty => b
  case Cons(y, ys) => reduce(f)(f(b)(y))(ys)
}

def map[A, B](f: A => B)(xs: XList[A]): XList[B] = reduce((b: XList[B]) => (a: A) => Cons(f(a), b).asInstanceOf[XList[B]])(XList.empty[B])(xs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either widen `Cons` to a `XList[B]` at the call site by providing the type parameters explicitly:

```
def map[A, B](f: A => B)(xs: XList[A]): XList[B] =
  reduce[A, XList[B]]((b: XList[B]) => (a: A) => Cons(f(a), b))(XList.empty[B])(xs)
```

Or use type ascription:

```
def map[A, B](f: A => B)(xs: XList[A]): XList[B] =
  reduce((b: XList[B]) => (a: A) => Cons(f(a), b): XList[B])(XList.empty[B])(xs)
```

---

As a side note, `reduce` is traditionally more strict at the method definition than what you've written. reduce usually looks like this:

```
def reduce[A](a0: A, a: A): A
```

Implicitly requiring a non empty collection to begin with. What you've implemented is similar in structure to a `foldLeft`, which has this structure (from Scalas collection library):

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Comment: Interesting to note that just switching the order of the arguments `f` and `b` in the `reduce` method's definition to match the order from the collection library's `foldLeft` also fixes the problem. I'm guessing that's why they did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two argument lists into one by replacing `)(` by `,`:

```
def reduce[A, B](f: B => A => B, b: B)(xs: XList[A]): B = xs match {
  case Empty => b
  case Cons(y, ys) => reduce(f, f(b)(y))(ys)
}

def map[A, B](f: A => B)(xs: XList[A]): XList[B] = 
  reduce((b: XList[B]) => (a: A) => Cons(f(a), b), XList.empty[B])(xs)
```

This will force the type inference algorithm to consider both first arguments of `reduce` before making up its mind about what `B` is supposed to be.